# Unknown Unity light distortion on Android

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've encountered some lighting strangeness on our Android build (see picture). The spotlight on the rocks produce what almost seems to be a z-fighting effect. This artifacting does not occur in the editor.

Things I've already checked:

- Shadows are turned off
- Pixel lights are cranked
- No compression on the textures (diffuse or normal map) - just for testing
- Clean build from Unity Cloud
- There are no lightmapping in the scene.
- Distortion is not present in iOS build.

Unity is 5.3.3p1

[image: Lighting issue on Android]